# Keycloak with nuxt-auth module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, oauth-2.0, nuxt.js, keycloak

I'm using [this auth-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-nuxt-auth-module) with Keycloak.

My configuration in nuxt.config.js:

```js
keycloak: {
    _scheme: 'oauth2',
    client_id: 'client-bo',
    userinfo_endpoint: 'SERVER/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo',
    authorization_endpoint: 'SERVER/protocol/openid-connect/auth',
    //userinfo_endpoint: false,
    access_type: 'offline',
    access_token_endpoint: 'SERVER/protocol/openid-connect/token',
    //response_type: 'code',
    response_type: 'token id_token',
    token_type: 'Bearer',
    token_key: 'access_token',
    scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
    redirect_uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/'        
}
```

The connection is OK.

When I click on the "connect" button, I am redirected to my Keycloak environment. Once authenticated by Keycloak, I am redirected to my nuxt.js application.

However, the problem is that my store is empty. Do you have any ideas about what causes this problem?

`loggedIn`: is always `false`

`user`: is always `null`

Can you tell me why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue, and was finally able to get it to work with the following configuration:

> package.json

```
 "@nuxtjs/auth-next": "5.0.0-1607534757.1122b76"
```

> nuxt-config.json

```
auth: {
keycloak: {
    scheme: 'oauth2',
    endpoints: {
        authorization: `${process.env.KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/realms/${process.env.KEYCLOAK_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/auth`,
        userInfo: `${process.env.KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/realms/${process.env.KEYCLOAK_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo`,
        token: `${process.env.KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/realms/${process.env.KEYCLOAK_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/token`,
        logout: `${process.env.KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/realms/${process.env.KEYCLOAK_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=` + encodeURIComponent(String(process.env.HOME_URI))
    },
    token: {
        property: 'access_token',
        type: 'Bearer',
        name: 'Authorization',
        maxAge: 1800 // Can be dynamic ?
    },
    refreshToken: {
        property: 'refresh_token',
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 // Can be dynamic ? 
    },
    responseType: 'code',
    grantType: 'authorization_code',
    clientId: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
    scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
    codeChallengeMethod: 'S256',
},
    redirect: {
        logout: '/',
        callback: '/',
        home: '/dashboard'
    },
}
```

Login function:

```
 login() {
  this.$auth.loginWith("keycloak");
},
```

I had seen that GitHub had issues reported on the Nuxt Auth module, but was able to get it to work with this configuration. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: thank you very much it works for me, I also followed this tutorial : https://tliebrand.com/19-programming/26-how-to-authorize-nuxt-against-keycloak

Comment: Just a heads up, the nuxt auth module is still in development mode and can introduce breaking changes, I could not get version 5.0.0-1613647907.37b1156 to work

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had to disable local auth. So in my nuxt config I had to set the following option:

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: false,
      keycloak: {...}
```

Hope this helps. (And I guess that you need the auth middleware on the page you are redirecting to)

Answer (score 0):

there is an option for vuex store, maybe this helps:

```
        watchLoggedIn: true,
        resetOnError: true,
        redirect: {
          login: '/login',
          logout: '/',
          callback: '/login',
          home: '/welcome'
        },
        vuex: {
          namespace: 'auth'
        },
        strategies: {
          keycloak: {
            _scheme: 'oauth2',
            authorization_endpoint: ...
```

What version of nuxt auth are you using ? I guess your store is set up properly and you are able to get values from it regarding other items ?